# Why does threadpool fill up when doing response-less HTTP Post?

Tags: android, multithreading, http

I am using an Android `AsyncTask` to POST some simple data to a server every second. The server did not return anything. However, I started seeing a ThreadPool error after only a short time of this activity. I quickly realized that for some reason threads were being created but never destroyed. I then sent a simple response back from the server upon each POST, and now it is working flawlessly. Why does this happen?

```
public class doPost extends AsyncTask {

        @Override
        protected Object doInBackground(Object[] objects) {
            double lat = (Double) objects[0];
            double longit = (Double) objects[1];

            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            // HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.1.110:3000/coord");
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(POSTURL);

            try {
                // Add your data
                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lat", Double.toString(lat)));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("long", Double.toString(longit)));
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            }

            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: My feeling is that the task is not done until the POST call returns, and it will not return until the server responds. Even if you use POST, the server still needs to confirm that the post was successful.

Comment: you mean, the server wasn't returning a 200 or something? Yeah @Daniel is probably right. You were hanging your thread because it was waiting to read a response. Did you ever get a timeout or anything? That would probably show up as an exception.

Comment: It's also worth being aware that AsynchTask uses a pretty limited thread pool. (Varies by Android version, but I believe ~8 is the most common.)

Comment: What error were you seeing?

Comment: I think all of these comments sound right. It seems interesting that the `AsyncTask` knows about whether the `HttpResponse` is finished or not; that the task waits until the response is done. I would think that the task would close upon 'return null' and the response would just be lost or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making a synchronous call, from a pool background thread, to http client:

```
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
```

This call will not return until the server responds. The `doInBackground` method will not even reach your return statement until the server responds. If you add a breakpoint on the `return` line, you can easily see that the return is not hit until the server responds.